# mysql fetch unique data with comma separated values

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I have mysql record like below

```
id country
 1  India
 2  Usa,Germany
 3  India,usa
 4  Germany,Uk,India
 5  Uk
```

I want to fetch country in drop down,
the data want to be display only unique country not duplicate entry and comma separate values

Drop drown list should be display like below

```
 India
 Usa
 Germany
 Uk
```

Comment: do i have to provide you the code example or just explanation would be enough?

Comment: Redesign (normalize) your database to eliminate comma-separated values in the table

Comment: @user2009951 please have a look at my answer i provided you the solution with complete code example. i quickly write code on local system and its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the full working example with databasse name `test` and table `table1`:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

   $query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
  $rows[]=$row['1']; //getting aal country
}


/* free result set */
$result->free();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
 ?>

 <form>
 <select>
 <?php foreach ($rows as $mod){?>
 <option value="<?php echo $mod?>"><?php echo $mod?></option>
 <?php }?>
 </select>
 </form>
 <?php $all_country = array();
 foreach ($rows as $mod){
     $arr = explode(',', $mod);
     foreach($arr as $row){ if(trim($row) != '')
         $all_country[] = trim($row);
         }
     }
     $input = array();
     $input = array_unique($all_country);
 ?>
  <form>
 <select>
 <?php foreach ($input as $mod){?>
 <option value="<?php echo $mod?>"><?php echo $mod?></option>
 <?php }?>
 </select>
 </form>
```

This is result: note that Uk and UK have uper and lower case problem else it is unique.

```
Simple data:
Array
(
    [0] => India
    [1] => Usa
    [2] => Germany
    [4] => usa
    [6] => Uk
    [8] => UK
)
unique country;


Array
(
    [0] => India
    [1] => Usa
    [2] => Germany
    [4] => usa
    [6] => Uk
    [8] => UK
)
```

Comment: There is no benefit to declaring the `value` attribute of an `<option>` when it is identical to the option tag's (visible) text value.  The redundant `value` value can be safely omitted -- all form submission and javascript processes will all still work normally.

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT country FROM table
```

In **PHP**

You can get array of `country`.

now on using `mysql_fetch_assco` you will have associative array.

Perform implode on that array values and them explode them by ,.

now perform array_unique on that array and you will have your array.

**Example**

```
$queriedResult = array
(
    'India',
    'Usa,Germany',
    'India,usa',
    'Germany,Uk,India',
    'Uk'
);

$result = implode(',',$queriedResult);
```

after that `$result` will be as below.

```
$result = 'India,Usa,Germany,India,usa,Germany,Uk,India,Uk';
```

now we are exploding above string by `,`.

```
$newArray = explode(',',$result);
```

we will have

```
$newArray = array
(
    'India',
    'Usa',
    'Germany',
    'India',
    'usa',
    'Germany',
    'Uk',
    'India',
    'Uk'
);
```

now perform final step.

```
$finalArray = array_unique($newArray);
```

produce.

```
$finalArray = array
(
    'India',
    'Usa',
    'Germany'
    'Uk'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider rethinking the model you store your data in. As you would want to use the **DISTINCT** keyword in your SQL statement to get unique countries.

If however you don't want to do that, you can use *explode* to get the comma seperated values.

Lets say we have your data in the array $results and you want your unique countries in the array $unique_countries

```
foreach($results as $result){
    $result_countries = explode(',',$result['country']);
    foreach($result_countries as $country){
        if(!in_array($country,$unique_countries)){
            $unique_countries[] = $country;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL query

```
select group_concat(country) from table
```

After that in php,

```
$duplicateCountry = explode(',',$sqlResult);
$duplicateCountry = array_unique($duplicateCountry);
```

gives your array.